# android studioでBuildに失敗する

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic2

ionicでハイブリッドアプリを開発しております。

ionicの環境を構築しandroid studioでビルドを行うと下記のエラーが出ます。

```
Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'app'.
```

ターミナルでは

```
ionic cordova build android
```

を行うと成功するのですが、android studioだとなぜか上記のエラーがでます。

試したこと
http://infotech776.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-64.html

**ツールのバージョン**
Android Emulator 29.0.11
Android SDK Platform-Tools 29.0.0
Android SDK Tools 26.1.1

**プロジェクトの名前.iml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">

    <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$" />
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

**ルートのbuild.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
task assemble{}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="28.0.3" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/193256

Answer (score 1):

defaultCompileSdkVersion=28　defaultTargetSdkVersion=28
　　　　　　　　　　　　   ↑と　　　　　　　　　　　　↑です。
                      これがエラーの原因でしょう(APIをそのAPIバージョンにして見て、駄目だったらもう一回考えて返信します)。

このTask 'assemble' not found in root project 'app'.であれば

ask clean(type: Delete) {　delete rootProject.buildDirを全部消すと実行できるかも